# Delegates in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to `Objective-C` and i am trying to understand [this](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002)

My question concerns:

```
[delegate sayHello:self];
```

As we know delegate is property. So how can it call the `sayHello` method of this protocol:

```
CustomClass *custom = [[CustomClass alloc] init]; // assign delegate

custom.delegate = self;

[custom helloDelegate];
```

What does the above line mean?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: the `delegate` has been set for the `CustomClass` then the `–helloDelegate` calls back the delegate class's `–sayHello:` method, which implementation is optional in the poor tutorial you are reading, so if you forgot to implement the `–sayHello:` method, your application will crash. use tutorials from more reliable sources, not every keen volunteer who has a nice website teaches you properly.

Answer (score 0):

delegate property is type of Id so it can store any kind of object in it.

so when you write delegate=self means your delegate contains current class's reference and when you call method using delegate it will call method implemented in current class.

Suppose we have two controller A and B.

Now You create Protocol and delegate property in B and Called some method of Protocol from Class B

suppose method name myMthod()

Now Delegate property of class B has reference of Class A

You have implemented the Protocol method in Class A.

Now If you want to call myMethod from Class A you will write
    [self myMethod];

If you call same method using delegate in Class B

```
[delegate myMethod];
```

and before this statement delegate=self is execute in Class A so there is no difference between above 2 Statements.

```
delegate = self // Statement execute in Class A // Delegate Has Class A's ref
```

now if you Call [delegate myMethod]; or [self myMethod]; both are same.

please refere this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-custom-delegates--mobile-10848) for more details.